# When I scale the picture, the others move jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote the next code with Jquery, which add in HTML document two images. These images are draggable and resizable. It nice, but I have one problem: when I drag the first image, the second so moves on HTML document. I need them to be independent. Who knows how to do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.draggable').draggable();
  $("img.resizebleImage").resizable();
});
```

```css
.resizebleImage {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body translate="no">

  <div class="draggable">
    <img class="resizebleImage" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>

  <div class="draggable">
    <img class="resizebleImage" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: use different class for both divs

Comment: Do both images follow your mouse when you drag one? Or does the other image fill the space you create when dragging the first image away?

Comment: Second version, i.e. others image fill the space  when i dragging the first inmage away. I tried use different class for both divs and it so doesn't @Glubus

Comment: The problem is the positioning of the images. The browser will dynamically position elements based on the space available, meaning if you allow for the image elements to be positioned statically, the browser will automatically fill up the space you create by dragging the other image. Try giving  the images an absolute positioning with CSS